# Calculating number of people in a room given entry and exit times using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, graph

I have a list of dates of when people went into a room and left it:

```
05/04/2017 14:20    05/04/2017 17:54
05/04/2017 13:10    06/04/2017 07:56
05/04/2017 10:30    05/04/2017 11:04
```

So a person entered at 14:20 and left at 17:54. A person entered at 13:10 one day and left at 07:56 the next.

What I would like to do is look at how many people were in the room between certain hours of the day, e.g. there were two people in the room between 14:00 and 15:00. I would then like to graph this data so I can see number of people in the room over different time periods.

My question is, is there a name for this kind of analysis and is this something that a package like Pandas can do. I can write an algorithm to do this (probably) but before doing that I wanted to check if it is a 'known problem'.

Answer (score 2):

Problems of this sort appear in different applications (e.g in physics it is called [mass balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_balance)), but AFAIK have no common name. But their essence is simple counting, so it is easier to write an algorithm than to find a solution to exactly your problem :)

This code calculates number of people that have entered or exited the room up to a given time, and then just subtracts the first from the second:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'in':[10, 11, 11, 12, 14], 'out':[11, 13, 15, 14, 15]})
count_in = data.groupby('in')['in'].count()
count_out = data.groupby('out')['out'].count()
count_data = pd.concat([count_in, count_out], axis=1).fillna(0).cumsum()
print(count_data['in'] - count_data['out'])
```

The code gives a result of:

```
10    1.0
11    2.0
12    3.0
13    2.0
14    2.0
15    0.0
```

It means that at 10 there was one person (who had just come), at 11 there were two (2 more came but 1 exited), etc.

Comment: @JohnE, groupby() method by default sorts the data by 'in' and 'out' respectively, so in my example you need not worry about sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a CSV file containing the list of dates, e.g.

```
05/04/2017 14:20,05/04/2017 17:54
05/04/2017 13:10,06/04/2017 07:56
05/04/2017 10:30,05/04/2017 11:04
```

Read each line and convert each entry into a Python `datetime` object. Next use a `Counter()` to note each entry and exit on a per hour basis. The datetime is used as a dictionary key with the minutes removed. Finally iterate over the available range of hours and add any entries or exits seen for each hour:

```
from collections import Counter    
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv

in_out = Counter()
one_hour = timedelta(hours=1)

with open('in_out.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_inout:
    for row in csv.reader(f_inout):
        in_at = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").replace(minute=0)
        out_at = datetime.strptime(row[1], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").replace(minute=0)
        in_out[in_at] += 1
        in_out[out_at] -= 1

hours = []
room_total = 0

hours_range = sorted(in_out.keys())     # Use to determine start and end hours
hour = hours_range[0]

while hour <= hours_range[-1]:
    room_total += in_out.get(hour, 0)
    hours.append((hour, room_total))
    hour += one_hour

for hour, room_total in hours:
    print(hour, room_total)
```

Which gives the following hourly breakdown:

```
2017-04-05 10:00:00 1
2017-04-05 11:00:00 0
2017-04-05 12:00:00 0
2017-04-05 13:00:00 1
2017-04-05 14:00:00 2
2017-04-05 15:00:00 2
2017-04-05 16:00:00 2
2017-04-05 17:00:00 1
2017-04-05 18:00:00 1
2017-04-05 19:00:00 1
2017-04-05 20:00:00 1
2017-04-05 21:00:00 1
2017-04-05 22:00:00 1
2017-04-05 23:00:00 1
2017-04-06 00:00:00 1
2017-04-06 01:00:00 1
2017-04-06 02:00:00 1
2017-04-06 03:00:00 1
2017-04-06 04:00:00 1
2017-04-06 05:00:00 1
2017-04-06 06:00:00 1
2017-04-06 07:00:00 0
```