# Maximum height of people in a room given entry and exit times

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, time-series

People arrive and depart a room at various times. Given their entry and exit times and their heights, what's an efficient way (in Python / Pandas) to find the maximum height of people in the room at all times?

Input:

```
people = pd.DataFrame({
    "height": [175, 180, 160],
    "arrive": pd.to_datetime(["2017-04-05 14:20", "2017-04-05 13:10", "2017-04-05 10:30"]),
    "depart": pd.to_datetime(["2017-04-05 17:54", "2017-04-06 07:56", "2017-04-05 11:04"])
})
```

Output:

```
[["2017-04-05 10:30", 160], ["2017-04-05 11:04", None], ...]
```

Explanation: The first person arrives at 2017-04-05 10:30 and his height was 160, so max height in the room was 160 since that time. This person left the room at 11:04 so max height was None since that time.

This problem is similar to [stackoverflow.com/q/47054341](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47054341) but the solutions are not satisfactory because we should not round off timestamps to the nearest hour.

Comment: What do you mean by "to find the maximum height of people in the room at all times?" Specifically the all times part. Do you have a list of dates and times, are you taking a user input, etc.? Where does `"2017-04-05 10:30"` come from in your expected output?

Comment: What I meant by all times is shown in the example output. `2017-04-05 10:30` was the time when the first person arrived, whose height is 160.

Comment: I understand that but why did you choose `2017-04-05 10:30` and not `2017-04-05 10:33`  or `2017-04-05 13:56` or any other arbitrary datetime for that matter. Where are the datetimes in your expected output coming from?

Comment: Because the maximum height of 160 took effect from `2017-04-05 10:30` rather than 10:33. The datetimes in my expected output come from the entry and exit times in the input.

Comment: Yes, but the maximum height of people in the room is still 160 at `2017-04-05 10:33` It is unclear what you are looking to accomplish based on the information provided. You should provide a complete expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Although max height is still 160 at 10:33, it's impractical to write something like `[[10:30, 160], [10:31, 160], [10:32, 160], [10:33, 160], ...]` as time is a continuous variable. I think the intention of my question is already clear from the example input and output. I've also referenced a similar question.

Comment: That is precisely my point - but if you think it is clear and not willing to provided me with additional information then hopefully someone else will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is an efficient way, but it may achieve what you want.

```py
import panda as pd

people = pd.DataFrame({
    "height": [175, 180, 160],
    "arrive": pd.to_datetime(["2017-04-05 14:20", "2017-04-05 13:10", "2017-04-05 10:30"]),
    "depart": pd.to_datetime(["2017-04-05 17:54", "2017-04-06 07:56", "2017-04-05 11:04"])
})

result = []
for time in sorted(list(people["arrive"]) + list(people["depart"])):
  cond = (people["arrive"] <= time) & (people["depart"] > time)
  result.append([str(time), people[cond]["height"].max()])

print(result)

"""
[['2017-04-05 10:30:00', 160],
 ['2017-04-05 11:04:00', nan],
 ['2017-04-05 13:10:00', 180],
 ['2017-04-05 14:20:00', 180],
 ['2017-04-05 17:54:00', 180],
 ['2017-04-06 07:56:00', nan]]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
# melt to move columns as rows
df2=df.melt(id_vars='height', var_name='status', value_name='date')

# set height as None for departed time
df2['height']=  df2['height'].mask(df2['status'].eq('depart'), 'None')

# groupby date and takes the max for each date
df2=df2.groupby('date', as_index=False)['height'].max() 
df2
```

```
date    height
0   2017-04-05 10:30:00     160
1   2017-04-05 11:04:00     None
2   2017-04-05 13:10:00     180
3   2017-04-05 14:20:00     175
4   2017-04-05 17:54:00     None
5   2017-04-06 07:56:00     None
```